A palavra "percepção" já teve o significado que atualmente se dá à "recepção"?
lendo a constituição federal, encontrei várias vezes este uso. Por exemplo:

§ 10. É vedada a percepção simultânea de proventos de aposentadoria
decorrentes do art. 40 ou dos arts. 42 e 142 com a remuneração de
cargo, emprego ou função pública, ressalvados os cargos acumuláveis na
forma desta Constituição, os cargos eletivos e os cargos em comissão
declarados em lei de livre nomeação e exoneração.

Houve uma mudança no sentido da palavra percepção?

Não, o sentido sempre esteve na língua moderna.

Sim. Para minha surpresa, não apenas já teve, como, de acordo com diversos dicionários, "perceber" ainda tem esse significado de "receber". Por exemplo:

Aulete:


percepção:
6. Jur. Cobrança do que é devido
7. Recebimento de quantia em dinheiro, remuneração


Priberam:


percepção:
2. Recepção.
3. Cobrança.


Houaiss:


percepção:
9 jur cobrança, arrecadação ou apropriação do que é devido
9.1 operação administrativa de recebimento ‹p. de impostos›


Michaelis:


perceber:
6 Receber ou recolher rendimentos; vencer.


Essa palavra vem do francês, aonde até hoje é a única com esse significado em linguagem administrativa. La perception des impôts. Acho que veio pelo Código Napoleônico.

Engraçado esse site. Uma resposta correta que não recebe muitos votos positivos, percebes? [piadinha com perceber. Sempre gostei da maneria que os portugueses dizem isso.]

@Lambie Hehe... 2 votos com 17 visualizações é razoável (e nem todas ocorreram depois de eu postar minhas resposta). Claro, poderia ser mais, mas acho que muitos pensam, como eu também pensava no início, que votos positivos são para respostas excepcionais, que merecem destaque, quando na verdade deveriam ser dados para qualquer postagem que faz uma contribuição positiva, ainda que não perfeita — isso aumentaria o número total de votos e evidenciaria melhor a qualidade das postagens. No caso específico dessa pergunta, ela é trivialmente respondida, o que pode desmotivar alguns membros a votar.

Trivialmente respondida? Acho que não.
